trigger azure action group from azure function
I want to implement logic using Azure Functions to trigger an Action Group in Azure Monitor.
(I'm not sure if this approach is incorrect.)
Initially, I implemented it in the code as follows.
def send_email_to_msp(user, token):
    subscription_id = os.getenv("AZURE_SUBS_ID")
    if subscription_id is None:
        logging.error("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID is not set.")
    else:
        logging.info(f"Subscription ID: {subscription_id}")
    resource_group = os.getenv("AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP")
    action_group_name = "MSP_COMMPANY"

    alert_name = f"Secret Key Expiry Notification for {user['displayName']}"
    alert_description = get_notification_message(user["notificationType"], user["displayName"], user["keyId"])["value"]

    uri = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/{action_group_name}?api-version=2019-06-01"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    body = {
        "alertContext": {
            "alertName": alert_name,
            "description": alert_description,
            "severity": "Sev3",  # Set appropriate severity level
            "alertTargetIDs": [user["displayName"]],  # Include any relevant IDs or target info
            "essentials": {
                "alertRule": alert_name,
                "severity": "Sev3",
                "signalType": "Log",
                "monitorCondition": "Fired",
                "monitoringService": "Platform",
                "alertTargetIDs": [user["displayName"]],
                "targetResourceName": user["displayName"],
                "alertDescription": alert_description,
                "firedDateTime": datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
            }
        }
    }

    try:
        response = requests.post(uri, headers=headers, json=body)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            logging.info(f"Alert sent to MSP action group {action_group_name} successfully.")
        else:
            logging.error(f"Failed to send alert to MSP action group. Status code: {response.status_code}")
            logging.error(f"Error details: {response.text}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to send alert to MSP action group: {e}")

When I ran it, it failed with the message
Failed to send alert to MSP action group. Status code: 401 [2024-08-07T02:04:33.232Z] Error details: {"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed."}}

Do you know what might be causing this?
and my app have permissions below:

I expect the users in the action group to receive an email.

trigger action group you need set permission at resource level (such as subscription, resource group of corresonding action group). not microsoft entra level

@wenbo thanks, your advise, but I am Owner for this subscription, How can I fix it ?

where you get the token? the token get from the principal (user, managed identity, or service principal, etc), this principal should have the right permission assigned.
